How to create a planner board with specific template with graph API
I am trying to create a planner board using graph api.
I am able to get the basic board. But instead I want to create a planner using lets say "Software Development" Template.
Or Option 2 would be to create a planner board than how to add a timeline using graph API itself
I have tried various codes given by chat gpt and also my basic ones.
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans
Content-Type: application/json
{
"owner": "gid",
"title": "SD",
"template": "Software Development"
}
The basic one with owner and title works and in this too it makes it but just without template.
Also tried "preferredtemplate" but that didn't work either.
